# Mapping specific columns of the first N results of one table to columns of another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a users table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    [id] int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [populartag1id] int NULL,
    [populartag2id] int NULL,
    [populartag3id] int NULL,

    constraint fk_populartag1id_users foreign key(populartag1id) references tags(id),
    constraint fk_populartag2id_users foreign key(populartag2id) references tags(id),
    constraint fk_populartag3id_users foreign key(populartag3id) references tags(id),
);
```

And a query

```
SELECT * FROM v_user_tag_counts ORDER BY userid, count DESC
```

that returns returns rows like these:

```
userid  tagid   count
7       1       2
7       161     1
7       26      1
7       2       1
8       150     1
8       98      1
8       89      1
8       20      1
8       157     1
8       19      1
8       289     1
8       116     1
```

Now I would like to map the first, second and third tagid returned from the query to columns populartag1id, populartag2id and populartag3id for all users in a single update (nightly job).

I'm note sure if PIVOT would be the correct approach here. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this through a manual pivot:

```
select ut.userid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ut.tagid end) as populartag1id,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ut.tagid end) as populartag2id,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then ut.tagid end) as populartag3id
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by userid order by count desc) as seqnum
      from v_user_tag_counts
     ) ut
group by ut.userid;
```

This format is suitable for inserting into the first table.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Is 'v_user_tag' supposed to be 'v_user_tag_counts'?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold . . . Yes.  I fixed that.